# PHP variables don't evaluate in the query

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I am pretty new to PHP and MySQL and I just can't figure this one out. I have searched all around the forum but haven't found an answer I can make sense of. I originally was using mysql_fetch_assoc() but I could only search numbers and I received errors when searching for letters as well. I hope I am on the right track here. Thank you in advance for all your help!

```
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("<script language='javascript'>alert('Unable to connect to database')</script>");
mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);

if (isset($_GET['part'])){
    $partid = $_GET['part'];
    $sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM $usertable 
        WHERE PartNumber = $partid';

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $partnumber = $partid;
    $nsn = $row["NSN"];
    $description = $row["Description"];
    $quantity = $row["Quantity"];
    $condition = $row["Conditio"];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to filter `$_GET['part']` to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This happens when your result is not a result (but a "false" instead).
You should change your code to this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM usertable 
    WHERE PartNumber = ?';

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $partid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

because you shouldn't add data variables in the SQL directly, but use placeholders instead. Given a placeholder cannot be used for a table name, it is generally a bad idea to make it a variable, so just write it as is.

Comment: It's because strings need to be escaped like above. I just improved my answer.

Comment: "This happens when your result is not a result (but a "false" instead)."

That really helped me debug in seconds.

Answer (score 17):

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

This means that the first parameter you passed is a boolean (true or false).

The first parameter is `$result`, and it is `false` because there is a syntax error in the query.

```
" ... WHERE PartNumber = $partid';"
```

You should never directly include a request variable in a SQL query, else the users are able to inject SQL in your queries. (See [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).)

You should escape the variable:

```
" ... WHERE PartNumber = '" . mysqli_escape_string($conn,$partid) . "';"
```

Or better, use [`Prepared Statements`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: http://www.macaerospace.info/inventory/test?part=1 works fine when it is just searching for a number |

http://www.macaerospace.info/inventory/test?part=PN123 does not work and gives me the boolean error|

Also, I received a T-VARIABLE error when inserting the escape string. Security is not a huge issue for me right now as I am just trying to get this to work first

Answer (score 2):

You are single quoting your SQL statement which is making the variables text instead of variables.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM $usertable 
    WHERE PartNumber = $partid";
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli makes use of object oriented programming. Try using this approach instead:

```
function dbCon() {
        if($mysqli = new mysqli('$hostname','$username','$password','$databasename')) return $mysqli; else return false;
}

if(!dbCon())
exit("<script language='javascript'>alert('Unable to connect to database')</script>");
else $con=dbCon();

if (isset($_GET['part'])){
    $partid = $_GET['part'];
    $sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM $usertable 
        WHERE PartNumber = $partid";

    $result=$con->query($sql_query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $partnumber = $partid;
    $nsn = $row["NSN"];
    $description = $row["Description"];
    $quantity = $row["Quantity"];
    $condition = $row["Conditio"];
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions, I could not test this code so you might need to tripple check it!

Comment: Your SQL query is invalid. You can `NOT` use variables in a single quote string

Answer (score -1):

What happens in your code if `$usertable` is not a valid table or doesn't include a column PartNumber or part is not a number.

You must escape $partid and also read the document for mysql_fetch_assoc() because it can return a boolean