# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given \Views\item.view.php on line 14

It's a prepared statement which returns 1 row. However, I can't get any data from it. I've tried a lot of solutions from other questions here, but they didn't work. I feel like I'm missing something small.

This is a part of item.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $item->getItem($id);
require 'Views/item.view.php';
```

This is item.class.php

```
public function getItem($id){
        include('/../config.php'); //contains the $mysqli
        
        $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM item WHERE id = ?") ;

        $result->bind_param("i", $id);

        $result->execute();
        
        
        if (!$result ) {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
        
    }
```

And the view

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
                        $row['title'];
```

EDIT: I also tried

```
while($post = $data->fetch_assoc()){ 

   $post['title'];
}
```

Which gives
*Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()*

config.php which is included, parameters hidden

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(adress, username, password, "trp");
```

EDIT2: This method from item.class.php does work

```
   public function getItems(){

    include('/../config.php');
    
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM item";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
    if (!$result ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $result;

}
```

With in the view

```
while($post = $data->fetch_assoc()){ 
$post['id']
}
```

EDIT:
Got it with

```
$result = $result->get_result();
```

and in the view

```
    while($post = $data->fetch_assoc()){ 

        echo $post['subject'];
}
```

Comment: You can't mix object-oriented and procedural styles like that. Use `$data->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347971/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-given)

Comment: Look http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Your SELECT results to false

Comment: @bub: uh, no it doesn't result to false. it resulted to an object.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Like "$row = $data->fetch_assoc();" ? Then I get
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in

Comment: @Rizier123 How is this a duplicate of that? First of all that's not my error and second I'm not using booleans. And that question isn't using a prepared statement.

Comment: *"First of all that's not my error"* - Funny, that's what both the title and what your question contains; so which or whose error is it... *really* then? - *"I am getting this error:

`Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given \Views\item.view.php on line 14`"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- His error is 'boolean given', mine is 'object given', also I've tried their solutions.

Comment: You may need to post a bit more code then, related to what's been posted in regards to included/required files. If you're using a class which seems to be the case, then add that also. It might also be a scope issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- allright I'll see what might be useful, thanks

Comment: If you're not quoting these `(adress, username, password,` then those are being treated as constants if you haven't defined them *from* constants. Otherwise, do as you did for `"trp"` and quote those also. `("adress", "username", "password", "trp")`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I did quote those, I just don't want to give my password and info

Comment: Ok. Well, only thing I can think of now is a scope issue which I did mention earlier. Try passing DB connection in your function `public function getItem($mysqli, $id){`

Comment: Sidenote: You do have a semi-colon at the end of `$post['id']` yes? Just need to dot the i's and bar the t's, as it were ;-) any progress?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything else. You may have to place `$id = $_GET['id'];` inside item.class.php and using `isset()` for the `$id...` - `if(isset($_GET['id'])){ $id = $_GET['id']{ // do something } else { echo "Not set"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with

```
$result = $result->get_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set parameters before executing $result.after

```
$result->bind_param("i", $id);
```

you have to set $id value..then you have to run

```
$result->execute();
```

if you need more info.please check this link and get a more clear idea..
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: $id is actually set by  $id = $_GET['id']; 
wich I didn't add, I thought that would be obvious. Sorry.