# Getting data from multiple tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1: Invoices (inv_id, inv_value, cust_id)
Table 2: Customers (cust_id, sales_rep)
Table 3: Members (Member_id, member_cateogry, member_type, cust_id)

Note 1: Each Customer Pays multiple Invoices. (One-to-Many Relationship).
Note 2: Each Customer pays for one-or-more members (so more than one member could be related to one customer).
Note 3: Each Member has a category which could be 1 "represents Individual" OR 2 "represents Group".
Note 4: Each Member has a type which could be 1 "represents new" OR 2 "represents renew".

I want to get the TOTAL of the `Invoice_value` field for customers who's `sales_rep` = 1 and their `member_category` = 10 and their `members_type` = 123
Ex: What is the total amount of Invoices that customers paid IF the Sales_rep for these customers was 1 and the members they paid for were new and Individual members.

I tried:

```
SELECT Sum(invoices.inv_value) AS total
FROM   invoices,
       customers,
       members
WHERE  invoices.cust_id = customers.cust_id
AND    members.custid = customers.cust_id
AND    members.category = {$category}
AND    members_type = {$type}
AND    customers.sales_rep = {$id}";
```

AND

```
SELECT     Sum(invoices.inv_value) AS total
FROM       members
INNER JOIN customers
ON         members.custid = customers.cust_id
INNER JOIN invoices
ON         customers.cust_id = invoices.cust_id
WHERE      customers.sales_rep = {$id}
AND        members.category = {$category}
AND        members.type = {$type}";
```

But both return double the Invoice value.
ex.: 1 Invoice for $120 in the Invoices table return $240 using these sql queries.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add sample table data giving different returned/expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Provide the table schema, relationship between tables, sample data and your expected result

Comment: Make sure that there is no duplication in `members.category` and `members.type` for the same `customer_id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Inner-join with 3 tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195451/sql-inner-join-with-3-tables)

Comment: @jarlh The expected result is a "single value" represents the total amount of Invoice values for specific customers.

Comment: @viki888 I've edited the question explaining the relations and the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT sum(i.inv_value) as total
FROM members m INNER JOIN
     customers c
     ON m.custid = c.cust_id INNER JOIN
     invoices i
     ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id
WHERE c.sales_rep = {$id} AND 
      m.category = {$category} AND
      m.type = {$type}";
```

(Don't use implicit `JOIN` syntax using commas.  It is archaic and less powerful.)

The problem is probably that two members can have the same customer id.  You can check this by running:

```
select m.cust_id, count(*)
from members m
group by m.cust_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

It is also possible that customer ids are duplicated in `customers`.

Assuming the duplicates are only in `members`, change the query to `exists`:

```
SELECT sum(i.inv_value) as total
FROM customers c
     ON  INNER JOIN
     invoices i
     ON c.cust_id = i.cust_id
WHERE c.sales_rep = {$id} AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM members m
              WHERE m.custid = c.cust_id AND
                    m.category = {$category} AND
                    m.type = {$type}
             );
```

Comment: Still returns Double the value :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are taking `inv_value` from `invoices`, which has **many to one** relationship with `customers` but `customer` table and `members` table have **one to many** relationship.

Say you have below data

**Invoice Table**

```
invoices.cust_id    invoices.inv_value
custid1                 100
```

**Customer table**

```
customer.cust_id
custid1
```

**Members Table**

```
members.cust_id     members.category
custid1                 1
custid1                 2
```

**On join all three tables**

```
customer.cust_id    members.cust_id         invoices.inv_value  members.category
custid1                 custid1                 100                 1
custid1                 custid1                 100                 2
```

if you notice as `custid1` exist in 2 `member_category`, `invoice value` is also duplicated.

To solve this, first you can take the distinct records, then summing those distinct records would help you solve your problem as below

**Solution**

```
SELECT Sum(invoices.inv_value) AS total
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT members.custid, invoices.inv_value inv_value
    FROM  members
    INNER JOIN customers
    ON members.custid = customers.cust_id
    INNER JOIN invoices
    ON customers.cust_id = invoices.cust_id
    WHERE customers.sales_rep = {$id}
    AND members.category = {$category}
    AND members.type = {$type});
```

Comment: Would you please review your code.
I think It makes sense but when I run it I got an error and no value is returned.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: The error would be due to the way you might have used in your code. Kindly check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347971/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-given)